# Flash error in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am crating a simple website which is already completed. I have tested on my localServer (localhost) which is working fine without any error.
But when i uploaded in my serve it throw a error

```
Warning (512): Method sessionHelper::flash does not exist [CORE/Cake/View/Helper.php, line 179]
```

could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Locally you are using Windows which is NOT case sensitive. The server where your application is hosted probably is case sensitive.

It is probably looking for `sessionHelper.php` which does not exist (actual name is SessionHelper.php).
You should review your code, i think you are trying to set the flash message with `$this->session->flash()` instead of `$this->Session->flash()`

Comment: i have used "$this->Session->setFlash('My Message');"
 instead of $this->Session->flash();
@noslone

Comment: Can you post your code? Including the `$components = array()` section where you load the Session component?

Comment: class AppController extends Controller { 
public $components = array(
        'Session',  
        'Auth'=>array(
            'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'admins', 'action'=>'home'), 
            'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login'), 
            'authError'=>"You can't access that page",  
            'authorize'=>array('Controller')
        )
    );

Ths is my code defined in 'AppController'.

Comment: sorry i did't get you.
What do you mean by log file?
@noslone

Comment: CakePHP log files are located in /tmp/logs. In most cases you can find more information about the errors in those files.

Comment: You should look for `session->flash()` in your views, not in your controllers. In controllers, `$this->Session` is an instance of the SessionComponent, not the SessionHelper.

Comment: i have reviewed my code where ''$this->Session->flash()'' is used not ''$this->session->flash()''

Comment: Also `Session::flash()` and `Session::setFlash()` are different methods in different classes.